# Adicionar Treeview Node pelo path

Tags: c#, treeview

Estu tentando adicionar um `TreeView Node` pelo path, por exemplo:

[image: TreeView]

E o código que estou tentando está assim:

```
public void AddParent(string path, string node)
{
    TreeNode parentNode = treeView1.Nodes[path];
    if (parentNode != null)
    {
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
}
```

Ex path: Node0\Node1\Node2
Ex node: Teste

Porem o parentNode sempre retorna `null`.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver meu problemas

Primeiro checo os nós principais:

```
public void AddParent(string path, string node)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tnode in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        if (tnode.FullPath == path)
        {
            tnode.Nodes.Add(node);
            break;
        }

        checkChildren(tnode, path, node);
    }

    treeView1.ExpandAll();
}
```

Depois checo os nós que são filhos:

```
public void checkChildren(TreeNode original, string path, string node)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tnode in original.Nodes)
    {
        if (tnode.FullPath == path)
        {
            tnode.Nodes.Add(node);
            break;
        }

        checkChildren(tnode, path, node);
    }
}
```

Thank's!